# 2D Game Development "God class"

Tags: c++, 2d-games, god-object

I am developing a 2D game in C++ using SFML API, but I am having an issue with class design.
I think that I am disobeying the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) because I have one main class called "Game" that should handle the window. It contains a method containing main game loop.
Now the problem; it contains object (composition) of more than 5 classes, such as Player, Menu, SplashScreen.
Do you think that it is a good idea to create such "God" class? Do you know any open source C++ 2D games from which I could learn?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you having problems with the design, or do you just want to think it through?  If you are not sure, sometimes it's not a bad idea to just continue coding with what you have and find out what's good and bad about it.  You will learn all sorts of things along the way.

Comment: I am just not sure. I have searched throughout stack overflow and found several posts regarding the "God" class (unfortunately they were not about game development). 
I, myself, do not think it is bad, but I have seen a few people saying that it is not a good habit to create such classes.

Comment: I agree with @paddy. If you've never done this kind of thing before, you will indeed learn a whole lot, and probably have several "misfires" before you feel comfortable with what you've written. As to your last question, try here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_video_games

Comment: If you avoid useful paradigms because of academic stigma, you will spend all your time refactoring code and never finish your project.  Just let it get a bit grungey and have fun making your game.  The next game you make will have better structure.  And the next....

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
I just do not want to learn bad habits, and that is why I have asked.
I will do what you have said; and when I finish the development, I will post here an article regarding my experience.

Comment: "unfortunately they were not about game development" <- how does that matter? Game development is software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/562146-c-avoiding-god-class/) on the Gamedev site about God classes (yes, they are a bad idea because tight coupling makes code less robust in the face of change).

Don't know about 2D, but there is a whole [GitHub repo](https://github.com/id-Software) with id-Software 3D game engines. Apart from the graphics, this should provide a treasure trove for you. See also the Doom [source code review](http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/index.php) for ideas on good coding style for writing games.

Comment: And what exactly should I consider as a god class? A class that has several responsibilities? 
If so, should a class that contains whole game loop be considered as a god class?
It also contains objects such as Player, SplashScreen etc. that have methods such as 'move', but they are all called inside the gameLoop method.

Comment: @Brukmoon Yes, many unrelated responsiblities that should be refactored into separate clases. see this [article](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/CoffeeMaker.pdf) for a small coding example.